# Pass timestamp with milliseconds to SQLAlchemy backed by SQLite3

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

It seems SQLAlchemy doesn't translate `filter` with a timestamp having fractional seconds properly to SQLite3:

`.filter(User.created_at <= datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1564004268.302929))`

But from what I've observed via debugging, only the seconds are passed to SQLite3 via SQLAlchemy. What's the correct way of performing this query?

I've also tried doing the comparison with just the float.

Comment: What does your model look like? Is the column data type DateTime or Float?

Comment: @Sazzy It's DateTime

Comment: Consider using a `datetime.datetime` object to do a comparison with instead of the `float`. You may see the raw value stored as a float in the SQLite database, but it gets converted to a datetime object internally.

Comment: @Sazzy Sorry, didn't realize that's what I am actually doing: `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1564004268.302929)` I tried just using the float, too. Updating my question now.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://gist.github.com/danielthiel/8374607#gistcomment-2377432